# Problems with using subset in r

Tags: r

I need to subset my data frame, but I do not know what condition to use.

```
df2<-subset(df, condition )

A part of the dataframe, `df`: 
state value     
a 1    
b 2    
c 3    
a 1    
b 4    
c 5
```

I count the sum of the `value` column for each state using : `table(df$state)`

I need to create a date frame where I show just the rows where the sum of the `value` column is bigger then a given value x. 
If x is  3, I need to have in the new data frame just the rows that have the "state" column equal to b or c.

What should I replace "condition" with? How can I use : `table(df$state)` in the condition?

Comment: Please don't use `<br>` code in your markup. It makes it a pain to look at and edit your question.

Comment: @Frank There is no reason to advise against interactive use of the `subset` function. You only should avoid using it inside functions.

Comment: @Roland Okay, that sounds familiar. I was scared off of using `subset` by that question and hadley's writeup, but didn't read them carefully. Please let me know if you think my last comment should be deleted. Yeah, actually, I'm going to go ahead and delete it, also because it advocated using the OP's table, which is incorrect as @agstudy pointed out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what are you trying to do.

`table(df$state)` count the occurence of each state in your data, not the sum of variable "value" for each "state".You should instead use something like this:

```
vv <- tapply(dat$value,dat$state,sum)
vv
a b c 
2 6 8
```

Now you can use the result within `subset`, to get the sum of the value column is bigger then a given value x. For example x == 3:

```
subset(dat,state %in% names(vv)[vv>3])
```

or without using `subset ( more efficient)

```
dat[dat$state %in% names(vv)[vv>3],]
```

Comment: So I solved my problem using this : vv <-table(df$state); df2<-subset(df,state %in% names(vv)[vv>x])